# Draw a function in ggplot2 with more than x as parameter

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I would like to draw a power-law function which depends on three parameters: `x`, `a`, and `gamma`. The function looks like this:

```
powerlaw <- function(x, a, gamma){
   a*(x**(-gamma))
}
```

Now I want to plot this but I cannot figure out how to specifiy `a` and `gamma` while telling R to use the chosen range for `x`. I tried this:

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(c(1,10), stat="function", fun=powerlaw(x, a=1, gamma=1), geom="line")
```

but it says

```
Error in (x^(-gamma)): x is missing
```

Of course, the following code works by fixing `a` and `gamma`:

```
powerlaw1 <- function(x){
   1*(x**(-1))
}
qplot(c(1,10), stat="function", fun=powerlaw1, geom="line")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the arguments separately:

```
qplot(x=c(1,10), stat="function", 
      fun=powerlaw, geom="line", 
      arg=list(a=1, gamma=1))
```

See `?stat_function` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I would just create a function which returns a `data.frame` appropriate for `ggplot2`:

```
power_data = function(x, a, gamma) {
   return(data.frame(x = x, y = a * (x**(-gamma))))
}

> power_data(1:10, 1, 1)                                           
    x         y                                                    
1   1 1.0000000                                                    
2   2 0.5000000                                                    
3   3 0.3333333                                                    
4   4 0.2500000                                                    
5   5 0.2000000                                                    
6   6 0.1666667                                                    
7   7 0.1428571                                                    
8   8 0.1250000                                                    
9   9 0.1111111
10 10 0.1000000
```

and make a plot (note that I use a more tightly spaced `x` series to get a smoother line):

```
dat = power_data(seq(1,10,0.01), 1, 1)
qplot(dat$x, dat$y, geom = "line")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul, that is also an interesting solution that I will surely use for a different problem. For the problem above, it was important to have a smooth curve, though. ggplot2 does a marvellous job at providing such a curve with the stat="function" option.

Comment: For a smooth curve you can just use an `x` with a smaller dx: `dat = power_data(seq(1, 10, 0.01), 1, 1)`.